# Prometheus join on metric value, rather than label?

Tags: prometheus

I have a Prometheus instance scraping from [snmp_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter), and
I have two metrics I need to join, with the aim to marry up IP addresses and network interfaces on SNMP-capable devices, based on the "ifIndex" number it is referenced by in SNMP:

| Metric | Value (ifIndex) |
| --- | --- |
| ifIndex{ifAlias="Cust:", ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/0/0", ifIndex="2", ifName="Gi0/1/0", instance="192.168.0.1", job="snmp"} | 2 |
| ipAddressIfIndex{instance="192.168.0.1", ipAddressAddr="1.1.1.1", job="snmp"} | 2 |

Both metrics return the ifIndex as a value, but only one includes it as a label. I'm familiar with how to join metrics based on matching labels, but so far have been unable to find a method for matching on the values.

I've also come at this the other way, by reconfiguring snmp_exporter to include an ifIndex label in ipAddressIfIndex. Undoubtedly this would be the preferred option, but documentation is unclear on how I might go about that, and experimentation has failed so far.

For background, the ipAddressAddr label contains the (redacted) IP of a second interface on the device, so sadly it's not as simple as using the instance address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such a join using `==` and `group_left`. For example provided in question something like this.

```
ifIndex == on(instance) group_left(ipAddressAddr) ipAddressIfIndex
```

This query will take all pair of metrics `ifIndex` and `ipAddressIfIndex` with the same `instance`, compare them, and return `ifIndex` with label `ipAddressAddr` of `ipAddressIfIndex` with the same value (if exists).

Example of similar "join" can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=go_info&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=up%20%3D%3D%20on(instance)%20group_left(version)%20go_info&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).